# Appending elements and replaceWith() - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, replacewith

i'm trying to give the user the possibility to update the values of some fields concerning him by clicking on a container named **#info-client**
Here I append the input areas after the click and once the **#finish** button is clicked the infos will then be updated.
The problem i got is that the infos were updated yet they were showed more than once ( 2 times or even 3 .. )

```
$("#info-client").one('click', function() {
  $("#info-client").children().hide();

  // liste des champs
  var c1 = $('<label> Nom : </label><input type="text id="identifiant"> <br>');
  var c2 = $('<label> Adresse : </label><input type="text" id="adresse"><br>');
  var c3 = $('<label> Ville : </label><input type="text" id="ville"><br>');
  var c4 = $('<label> Tel : </label><input type="text" id="tel"> <br>');
  var c5 = $('<label> Fax : </label><input type="text" id="fax"> <br>')
  var button = $('<input type="button" id="finish" value="Mettre à jour">');

  $("#info-client").append(c1);
  $("#info-client").append(c2);
  $("#info-client").append(c3);
  $("#info-client").append(c4);
  $("#info-client").append(c5);
  $("#info-client").append(button);

  $("#finish").one('click', function() {
    var identifiant = $('#identifiant').val();
    var adresse = $('#adresse').val();
    var ville = $('#ville').val();
    var tel = $('#tel').val();
    var fax = $('#fax').val();

    c1.replaceWith("<h4>" + identifiant + "</h4>");
    c2.replaceWith("<p> Adresse : " + adresse + "</p>");
    c3.replaceWith("<p>" + ville + "</p>");
    c4.replaceWith("<p>Fax : " + tel + "</p>");
    c5.replaceWith("<p> Tel :" + fax + "</p>");

  });
});
```

Comment: Could you setup an example of the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net? Or at least add your HTML to the question

Comment: Here it is :
https://jsfiddle.net/3h79cv7o/

Comment: You have to know that `$("#info-client")` makes a DOM request and creates a jQuery object every time it's executed. You could largely optimise your code by caching it : `var $infoClient = $("#info-client"); $infoClient.somestuff(); $infoClient.otherStuff();` You can also chain instructions : `$infoClient.append(c1).append(c2).append(c3)`

Answer (score 0):

See what's happening is once you've clicked `#info-client` for the first time, it puts all of the form elements INSIDE `#info-client`. So when you click on any of the input boxes, including `#finish` (all of which are inside `#info-client`), it triggers the on-click function (I'm assuming you misspelled `on()`) and hides and adds everything again.

What you could do, instead, is have the form initially on the screen but hidden from view. When a certain trigger button is clicked, rather than writing the form elements to screen, you simply show the form. This way, you're not rewriting the form every time `#info-client` is hit, and it'll also be easier to manage `#finish`.

See if that helps.